# UITableViewCell checkmark change on select

Tags: objective-c, iphone, tablecell, checkmark

Am I correct in thinking that to change the checkmark for "on" to "off", I must change the `CellAccessoryType` between `none` and `checkmark` on the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Because I have done this but I have noticed the behaviour is not perfectly identical to like the checkmark cells on the auto lock settings on the iphone.

Or is there some other way checkmarks are meant to be handled?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

1. Keep a property in your view controller called `selectedRow`, which represents the index of a row that represents the checked item in a table section.
2. In your view controller's `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, set the `accessoryType` of the `cell` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` if the cell's `indexPath.row` equals the `selectedRow` value. Otherwise, set it to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`.
3. In your view controller's `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, set the `selectedRow` value to the `indexPath.row` that is selected, e.g.: `self.selectedRow = indexPath.row`

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean that I had multiple checkmark cells (more like radio buttons). Just they didn't animate as smoothly (but I fixed that now). But your answer means I am using the correct methods :)

Comment: To add to Alex's solution - to make the check mark appear when you tap the cell, you must also put in [tableview reloadData] after you set the selected cell.

Comment: That's easy, but there might be a performance hit from reloading data into the whole table. Because you know what `indexPath.row` you need to update, you only need to update that row, which can be done with the table view method `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` For more details: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW40

Comment: @AlexReynolds can you please elaborate when you said 

set the accessoryType of the cell to UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark if the cell's indexPath.row equals the selectedRow value. Otherwise, set it to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone.

Comment: Either the row needs a checkmark, or it doesn't. If it is the selected row (by comparing the index path row and selected row values) then mark it. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: I did this, but the checked box stays highlighted in gray instead of fading out like it does in apple apps.

Answer (score 61):

Another solution:

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSIndexPath *oldIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndex].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    return indexPath;
}
```

And yeah: you don't have to check if `oldIndex` is `nil` :)

---

Swift 3 and later:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if let oldIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: oldIndex)?.accessoryType = .none
    }
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

    return indexPath
}
```

Comment: This is really a great code. I added the Swift version.

Answer (score 5):

swift:

```
var selectedCell:UITableViewCell?{
    willSet{
        selectedCell?.accessoryType = .None
        newValue?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
}
```

then:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.mapView.annotations[indexPath.row], animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Excellent approach to the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For swift

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Zyphrax suggested a great solution that worked great for me! And if you need to clear the previous selected row, just use:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

> didHighlightRowAtIndexPath

instead of

> tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 3):

Alex answer worked for me only after adding reload table , 
**in .h**

```
{
  int selectedCell;
}
@property(nonatomic,readwrite)int selectedCell;
```

**in .m**
**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
if(indexPath.row == selectedCell)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.selected = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selected = NO;
    }
```

**and in anywhere didHighlightRowAtIndexPath  or didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
 self.selectedCell = indexPath.row;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to use your custom image as accessoryType use below code**

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIImageView *imgCheckMark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_icon.png"]];
    [imgCheckMark setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 30, 25, 14, 18)];
    imgCheckMark.tag = 1000+indexPath.row;

    NSIndexPath *oldIndex = [self.tblSelectService indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tblSelectService cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndex].accessoryView = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [self.tblSelectService cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = imgCheckMark;
    return indexPath;
}
```