# Scroll TableView to check mark the tableview cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using touch event in the tableview to select the tableview cell.I want to tableview to scroll slowly to select tableview cell.And when Im reaching last visible cell inside the frame i want to cell to scroll one by one.Below my code scrolls but not accurate.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    self.scrollEnabled = YES;
 }
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    self.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    self.scrollEnabled = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)swipedIndexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"%f",location.y);
        NSArray *visibleRows = [self indexPathsForVisibleRows];
        NSIndexPath *firstPath = visibleRows[0];
        NSIndexPath *secondPath = visibleRows[1];
        CGRect firstRowRect = [self rectForRowAtIndexPath:firstPath];
        [self scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(firstRowRect.origin.y > self.contentOffset.y ? firstPath : secondPath) atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Checked";
    [self reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[swipedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}
```

can have any other option or what Im doing wrong here

Comment: Why do you need to use touches delegate when you can easily do it using UITableView Delegate methods.. Check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797165/uitableviewcell-checkmark-change-on-select and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I know to how to checkmark a tableview with didselect..But i use touch moved such that i can get touched indexpath.But when i reach last cell the tableview should scroll automatically one by one cell.Such that i can checkmark the upcoming cells just by holding the the frame bottom