# I'm having custom tableview cell and I set a overall button at a bottom of a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDROD.jpg)I'm having custom tableview cell and I want to set a overall button at a bottom of a tableview with clickable

```
UIButton*yourBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[yourBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wishlist"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[yourBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
yourBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height -100, buttonwidth, buttonheight);
yourBtn.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.bounds.size.height -100);
[yourBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:yourBtn];
```

**if i scroll tableview button also scroll from top to bottom.i want to set that button constant when scroll tableview**

How to get a tableview button like this

Comment: why you not use storyboard it's more easy

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a table footer? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView

Comment: try this [self.tableview addSubview:yourBtn];

Comment: if i scroll tableview button also scroll from top to bottom.i want to set that button constant when i scroll tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the `tableview` and the `button`.

Here is the code:

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - 70,
                            CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - 70,
                            50,
                            50);
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Untitled-1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:yourButton];
```

I hope the above information is helpful for you.

Comment: if i scroll tableview button also scroll from top to bottom.i want to set that button constant when i scroll tableview

Comment: Okay then you better separate the tableview and the button. Place your button under the tableview and it will stay there while you're scrolling. There is no other way around.

Comment: I updated the answer. You can also download the sample project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lju3fsth15s6zm7/werwer.zip?dl=0

Comment: its working sir..in that how to get checkmark in selected uitableview cell

Comment: You can find that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797165/uitableviewcell-checkmark-change-on-select